# PostgreSQL: ERROR: cannot execute CREATE DATABASE in a read-only transaction

Tags: postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL and and its GUI, pgAdmin III.
Setup already had a default database postgres.

When I am trying to create a new table or database, it is showing an error:

> ERROR:  cannot execute CREATE DATABASE in a read-only transaction

I uncommented the line `default_transaction_read_only = off` in postgresql.conf and executed the command `pg_ctl start -D /home/jaison/progresData -Z datanode -l logfile` but it is still showing the same error.

please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

You could always double check your problem by issuing a command such as

`/usr/bin/pgsql/bin/createdb test`

You can frequently get better/clearer error messages and/or other information from the command line than from GUI tools such as pgAdmin III.

But, in order to change a system parameter, you have to reload the `postgresql.conf` file after making changes. You can do this by either

- rebooting the server or
- reloading the .conf file or
- change on the client side

From [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/config-setting.html), some parameters always need a reboot and some can be dynamically changed by simply reloading.

I tried to find a clear list of those which required reboot and which required reload, but failed (grateful for input on this!).

**For a system reboot,**

[`pgctl restart`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pg-ctl.html)

To reload, you could also try these commands (from [here](http://www.heatware.net/databases/postgresql-reload-config-without-restarting/) - or check the documentation page given above).

**Option 1: From the command-line shell**

```
su - postgres /path/to/pg_ctl reload
```

**Option 2: Using SQL**

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

You can verify that the setting has "taken" from the table pg_settings. Also of interest is this [page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config.html).

For the `default_transaction_read_only` parameter, you can also set it directly from the client (see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-client.html)). Check the links [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config.html) for how to set all parameters - reboot, reload or client.

```
test=# SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'default_transaction_read_only';
             name              | setting 
-------------------------------+---------
 default_transaction_read_only | on
(1 row)

test=# 
test=# `SET default_transaction_read_only = OFF;`
SET
test=# 
test=# SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'default_transaction_read_only';
             name              | setting 
-------------------------------+---------
 default_transaction_read_only | off
(1 row)

test=# 
test=# SET default_transaction_read_only = ON;
SET
```

Comment: I am extremly sorry..But I was not able to check the post due to some reasons. But this post seems to be very useful. thank you very much

Comment: @jaison - if you think that the answer is correct, please mark it as such. This will help those looking for answers to the same or similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

First check your transaction mode using the query
"SHOW default_transaction_read_only;" if it is "on" change it to "off" by using the command "SET default_transaction_read_only = OFF;", now you can start your normal transactions.